# How to close editing window appeared in terminal?

Tags: git, github, terminal

I am going to update my branch on git hub with original one.
So I type:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
merge upstream/master
```

When I trying to type `merge upstream/master` from my terminal a new window appear on it.

[image]

How to proceed?

Comment: Your screenshot didn't upload, please fix it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you would like to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a text editor, so that you can edit the merge commit message. The message says to

> Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary...

If you want to find what text editor it is, you should be able to follow the instructions in https://askubuntu.com/questions/615178/getting-the-default-text-editor-used-in-system

Comment: If this is vim, why can't move using h,j,k,l. If type : it is not showing any thing, only it appearing with other sentences.

Comment: It is different for each computer, that's why I just explained how to find it.